# Dropdown panel is moving 30px to the left on click of search in Angular

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using `Angular`, `Angular Material` and `css`

```
<mat-select disableOptionCentering class="sort-portals" value="newest" panelClass="custom-panel-order-types">
    <mat-option value="newest">Newest</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="oldest">Oldest</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="ascending">Sort A to Z</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="descending">Sort Z to A</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

The `sort-portals` class is defined as below...

```
.sort-portals {
    background: $white;
    max-width: 150px;
    margin-left: 880px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 11.5px;
}
```

The `panelClass` is defined as below...

```
.custom-panel-order-types {
  margin: 34px 0px !important;
  min-width: 150px !important;
  margin-right: 5px !important;
  width: 30px !important;
}
```

The problem here is on load of the page for the first time, the Dropdown panel aligns properly to the dropdown textbox. But, when I enter some id in the search box and press enter, the width of the page increases and the alignment of the Dropdown panel moves to the left by 20px and it looks as below..

[image: Alignment of Dropdown Panel]

**EDIT**

When I use appearance as `outline` with `mat-form-field`, it appears like below...and is left aligned to the page..

[image: Appearance]

Comment: Is there any possible way setting the margin of the `Dropdown Panel` after the `DOM` completely loads in that page?

Comment: I think you shouldn't change the width of mat-select panel because it's used in the computation of absolute position. Why did you add the `width: 30px`? Can you reproduce the error in stackblitz for example?

Comment: I have removed the `width` and it is working for the first time. It works the same way as before. But not responsive. What should I set for `margin-left: 880px` here? I am not comfortable in creating Stackblitz example.

Comment: I think the problem is that you've added padding to mat-select which is used in the computation. If you want to style the angular material form element you should use it inside `<mat-form-field>` component, can you try this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try the below CSS, do not modify the CSS of `mat-select` instead add padding to the child `mat-mdc-select-trigger`.

```
.sort-portals {
  background: white;
  max-width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex !important;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.sort-portals .mat-mdc-select-trigger {
  padding: 0px 15px;
}

.custom-panel-order-types {
  margin: 34px 0px !important;
  min-width: 150px !important;
}
```

[<kbd>**`Stackblitz Demo`**</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/iuvb3p-wxddag?file=src%2Fexample%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.html,src%2Fexample%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.ts,src%2Fstyles.scss,src%2Findex.html)

Comment: With this code, the `Dropdown Box` is displaying to the left hand side of the screen. I would like to have it right aligned..

Comment: @CPK_2011 In the parent element add `display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between;` If there are two elements in the parent element, both will get aligned to the corners! Basically use the parent to do the alignment instead of the element!

Comment: Alignment to the right side is missing..

Comment: @CPK_2011 possible to update the image and the latest code you are using?

Comment: Your answer is helpful. There is problem with my code.

Comment: @CPK_2011 ok hope its resolved!

Comment: Your Answer is very helpful to me. Marked as Answer! @Naren-Murali

Comment: Could you please help me on other 2 Questions?